# R lme4 getting vastly different results than Python statsmodels for same(?) model

Tags: r, python, lme4-nlme, statsmodels

I'm trying to do a mixed model in python. I have some experience in R but am fairly new to doing these analyses in python

I'm running what I think are the same models in python and R, using the same data from a CSV file, and am getting weird results.

in R:

```
model_full <- lmer("Score ~ Time + (Time|Condition)", data=data)
```

what i *think* is the same model in python:

```
model = sm.mixedlm('Score ~ Time', data=data, groups='Condition', re_formula='Time').fit()
```

But in python it's giving me warning that it didn't converge. Did I convert this formula properly into python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as though you've forgotten a tilde in the random effect argument. [Here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/mixed_lm_example.html) is a summary of the method.  Note that it looks like the authors experience convergence warnings too for what is a very rudimentary model.

Note that it looks like the convergence issues can be skirted by passing `method='cg'` to the `.fit` method as per [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5546).  Alternatively, you could pass `method=<name of scipy optimizer you want to use>`.  For what its worth, I'm not a huge fan of statsmodels, and would recommend R over statsmodels all day long.

Comment: Could you give some detail what the tilde is doing?

Comment: @AdamB Take a look at the patsy library.  It turns the expression into a patsy formula which statsmodels uses in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

- You can see the gradient vector at wherever the algorithm terminated using: `model.score(rslt.params_object)`.  If the gradient is small, you may have effectively converged despite the warning.
- Python almost always gives warnings when the MLE of a variance parameter is on the boundary of the parameter space.  These warnings are coming form the scipy optimizers, which don't know how to judge convergence to the boundary of a compact set.  I believe R has some logic to detect this and silence any warnings (since the gradient need not be small in this type of convergence).

Statsmodels MixedLM is slow compared to R, but I am not aware of any examples where it fails to converge but R does converge, or where it converges to the wrong value (but R converges to the right value).  The statsmdels/scipy algorithms may produce more warnings than in R, but these warnings are often spurious.  Selecting an alternative optimizer may help in some cases.

Comment: By the way, if you can share the data (privately if necessary) I can take a look.

Comment: Hmm that’s interesting. Warnings are usually to warn about something bad. Seems like a bit of an oversight by the creators. Thanks for the offer. I’ll ask about sharing data, it’s not mine. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: When try to check the gradient, there’s no object rslt. Am I missing something?

Comment: `rslt` should be the Results instance returned by `fit`. You called it `model`, but it's an instance of the results class and not the model class.

Comment: Ah ok so I should store model separately and then rslt = model.fit?

Comment: Yes, something like this: `model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula(...)` then `rslt = model.fit(...)` than `model.score(rslt.params_object)`

Comment: Fitting a mixed model involves optimizing a function that can be very flat and not convex.  The estimate lying on the boundary of the parameter space is an additional challenge.  All mixed modeling software faces these challenges.  Also, because statsmodels uses scipy optimizers, it's a bit harder to fine-tune exactly when warnings are emitted.